# Prestashop 1.7.5 and PayPal plugin version 5.4.0 error: The value of a field is either too short or too long

Tags: php, paypal, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a PrestaShop 1.7.5 and have upgraded recently PayPal to version 5.4.0
seems the update has broken the payments
the PayPal pop up is displaying and then I get the error message

**Error code: 0;Short message: The value of a field does not conform to the expected format.;**

I have found this topic
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1038873-issues-with-paypal-v531/?do=findComment&comment=3292187

but after changing the rouding numbers form 3 to 2 I get agin an error from PayPal

**Error code: 0;Short message: The value of a field is either too short or too long.;**

can anyone help?

```
(1/1) ContextErrorException
Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
in custompopup.php line 386
at CustomPopup->functionHook(array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 2))in custompopup.php line 83
at CustomPopup->__call('hookdisplayFooter', array(array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 2)))in Hook.php line 966
at HookCore::coreCallHook(object(CustomPopup), 'hookdisplayFooter', array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 2))in Hook.php line 351
at HookCore::callHookOn(object(CustomPopup), 'displayFooter', array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 2))in Hook.php line 903
at HookCore::exec('displayFooter', array('smarty' => object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 2), null)in smarty.config.inc.php line 165
at smartyHook(array('h' => 'displayFooter'), object(SmartyDevTemplate))in SmartyLazyRegister.php line 83
at SmartyLazyRegister->__call('smartyHook', array(array('h' => 'displayFooter'), object(SmartyDevTemplate)))in 5debc5491c55490fb70872b4b8ac73e7c4b076d5_2.file.footer.tpl.php line 92
at Block_261192810604657b04b0269_01194600->callBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 248
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->callBlock(object(Block_261192810604657b04b0269_01194600), object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 184
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->process(object(SmartyDevTemplate), object(Block_261192810604657b04b0269_01194600))in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 156
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->instanceBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'Block_261192810604657b04b0269_01194600', 'hook_footer')in 5debc5491c55490fb70872b4b8ac73e7c4b076d5_2.file.footer.tpl.php line 39
at content_604657b04b3ee8_66053338(object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()in smarty_internal_template.php line 385
at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('file:_partials/footer.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', 0, 3600, array(), 0, false)in e8aae06b74c347ba1d8da54e2a9d5a9f73bac7c7_2.module.paypalviewstemplatesfront.php line 163
at Block_1467223895604657b03129d9_88778906->callBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 248
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->callBlock(object(Block_1467223895604657b03129d9_88778906), object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 184
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->process(object(SmartyDevTemplate), object(Block_1467223895604657b03129d9_88778906))in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 156
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->instanceBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'Block_1467223895604657b03129d9_88778906', 'footer')in e8aae06b74c347ba1d8da54e2a9d5a9f73bac7c7_2.module.paypalviewstemplatesfront.php line 99
at content_604657b0314b23_85855752(object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render(false, 0)in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 232
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(object(SmartyDevTemplate), null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', null, 0)in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('module:paypal/views/templates/front/payment_error.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', null, false, true, false)in SmartyDev.php line 40
at SmartyDev->fetch('module:paypal/views/templates/front/payment_error.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl')in FrontController.php line 682
at FrontControllerCore->smartyOutputContent('module:paypal/views/templates/front/payment_error.tpl')in FrontController.php line 666
at FrontControllerCore->display()in Controller.php line 301
at ControllerCore->run()in Dispatcher.php line 509
at DispatcherCore->dispatch()in index.php line 28
```

Comment: Probably best to ask for help on PrestaShop's forums for this issue

Comment: have done that as well, https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1044514-paypal-v540-on-presta-1750/?tab=comments#comment-3313773